# grok not reading a word with hyphen

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok

This is my grok pattern

2017-09-25 08:58:17,861 p=14774 u=ec2-user |   14774 1506329897.86160: checking for any_errors_fatal

I'm trying to read the user but it's giving only ec2 , it's not giving the full word

Sorry i'm newer to the grok filter

My current pattern :

%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} p=%{WORD:process_id} u=%{WORD:user_id}

Current output :

```
...
...
...
  "process_id": [
    [
      "14774"
    ]
  ],
  "user_id": [
    [
      "ec2"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: it's working .. %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} p=%{WORD:process_id} u=%{USERNAME:user_id}

Comment: If you use USERNAME, someone maintaining your code may think that the log contains a, um, username.  Make your own pattern as described by Vorsprung

Answer (score 9):

WORD is defined as `"\b\w+\b"`

See https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns

- \b is a word boundary
- \w matches a single alphanumeric character (an alphabetic character, or a decimal digit) or "_"
- + means any number of the previous character. So \w+ means any number of characters

Note that \w does NOT match -

So to make it work instead of WORD use

```
(?<user_id>\b[\w\-]+\b)
```

This does not use the preddefined grok patterns but "raw" regexp

- the (?....) is used instead of %{ as it is "raw" regexp
- `\-` means a literal - sign
- [ ] means a character class.  So [\w-] will match all the things \w does and - as well

Comment: Or you can use USERNAME like in the comment that I didn't read.  *Sigh*

Answer (score 1):

**Input**Allow1-2 : Success

**Grok Filter**(?:%{GREEDYDATA:Output}?|-)

**Result**
{"Output":[["Allow1-2 : Success"]]}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)